# How can I restructure and normalize table1 into table2 like this?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table1 is like this

```
Id | Name    | Subject
1   |Rakesh  | English
1   |Rakesh  |  Maths
1   |Rakesh  | Science
2   |Mukesh  | English
2   |Mukesh  |  Maths
```

---

Table 2 which I want is like this:

```
Id  | Name   | Subject
1   | Rakesh | English, Maths, Science
2   | Mukesh | English, Maths
```

Comment: That would be 'de-normalising'. This kind of thing is best handled in application code

Comment: First normal form (1NF) specifies that attributes should be atomic, and your second table violates this. If you want to normalize Table 1 you should split it into two tables.

Comment: And please only tag the db that you're using

Comment: Well, actually 3 tables

Comment: You can have a  look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad maj´ke for you an interesting reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following. Here is the [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe90af/2)

**MySQL**

```
 select 
   id, 
   name, 
   group_concat(subject order by subject SEPARATOR ', ') as subject
 from table
 group by
   id,
   name
```

**SQLite** - As `order by` not an option inside `group_concat`, you can do something like following

```
select
    id,
    name,
    group_concat(subject, ', ') as subject
from
(
 select 
   id, 
   name,
   subject
 from student
 order by
    id, subject
)
group by
    id, name
```

Comment: You need a group by id,name otherwise the aggregate function will be over the whole result set

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks.

Comment: It works but I want to save it in table. with this query it is just displaying in required format and not saving it @zealous

Comment: @coldbloded just do `create table yourTableName` and then put query. this article may be helpful to you https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html